# logic word question

Tags: logic

having trouble with this question, done others similar to it but i cant seem to figure out this one.

three logic students walk into a cafe. The barista asks "Does everyone want a latte?" the first student says "i don't know". So does the second student. The third student then says "Yes!". is he right? explain.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  suppose the first student didn't want one.  What would they say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He indeed is right, if he wants latte himself.

The point is, that the one who answer when there is somebody who will answer after him doesn't know the next's answer. So even if the first one wants the beverage, he can't say *yes*, because the question is 'does **everyone** wants a latte'? So he says he doesn't know, so does the second and the third one answers according to his will. *Yes* if he wants one, *no* if he doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If the first student didn't want a latte, he would have answered no, because then not everyone would want a latte. Then, the first student wants a latte.

Similarly, the second student wants a latte.

Then, the third student knows the first two want a latte. If he wants one, he can safely answer that everyone wants a latte. So, if he wants a latte, the third student is right.

Comment: thanks that makes so much more sense now

Answer (score 0):

For me it doesn't make any sense. The third student doesn't know if the other two wants a latte or not, so when he says "yes", he may very well make them drink something they don't want to. So he isn't necessarily right.

IF you assume that "I don't know" from student 1 and student 2 means "yes I want a latte", then and only then is the reasoning that the last one says "yes" for all correct.

For me the most logical answer would be that everyone says "I don't know".